# Floating point in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

The code below always returns 0.0000000. I don't know why it is doing this.

here is the code

```
SECTION .data
flt1:   dq  5.327
formatin: db "%f", 0
SECTION .bss

SECTION .text
   global _main 

   extern _scanf 
   extern _printf     

_main:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
push dword[flt1]    

push formatin
call _printf
add esp, 8


    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

can you help me fix this problem so I can display numbers with a decimal point

Comment: in nasm x86 on windows 8

Comment: The C convention is to pass `float` as `double`.  Try `push qword[flt1]`

Comment: @wallyk in 32 bit mode there is no `push qword`, it must be done differently, for example through `fld`/`fstp`, SSE/MMX, or simply as 2 dwords. Also the `add esp, 8` has to be adjusted.

Comment: The parameter for `scanf` is the address of the number, not the number. (K&R calls this "the most common error") Try `push flt1`. As noted, `printf` always wants a double.

Answer (score 1):

In c function calls, `float` is promoted to `double`. You also declared `flt1` as `dq`, a double. So regardless, you need to pass a 64-bit type. If you are on a 64-bit system, simply use `push qword[flt1]`. If you are on a 32-bit system, you will have to instead use `fld`. Because your parameter sizes are different, you will then have to use `add esp, 12` rather than `add esp, 8`